# How to configure VPN in Ubuntu?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Graphically illustrate me please, new to Ubuntu

Comment: You mean a connection or a server?

Comment: Ubuntu Documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about graphically, I'm not sure an easy to use GUI exists for setting this up, so here's the easiest way of doing it via the terminal.

When you're in the command-line install UFW (it's easier than iptables and does the job just fine) and pptpd (the VPN server):

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install ufw pptpd
```

Then allow HTTP, HTTPS, and pptpd (1723).

```
sudo ufw allow 1723
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

Now open up the /etc/ppp/pptpd-options file for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
```

And comment-out the following lines, by adding a # symbol in front:

```
#refuse-pap
#refuse-chap
#refuse-mschap
#require-mppe-128
```

Also in that file, add the following (this is using OpenDNS' DNS servers):

```
ms-dns 208.67.222.222
ms-dns 208.67.220.220
```

Now open up the /etc/pptpd.conf file for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/pptpd.conf
```

And at the bottom of the file add the following:

```
localip 10.99.99.99
remoteip 10.99.99.100-199
```

The above IP addresses do not need to correspond to your network, so just use the above.

Now open up the /etc/ppp/chap-secrets file for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

In this file add a username and password like this (separate the fields by a tab):

```
username    pptpd    password    *
```

Now open up the /etc/sysctl.conf file for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And uncomment the line (remove the # symbol):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Now open up the /etc/default/ufw for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/ufw
```

And change `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"` to `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`

Now open up the /etc/ufw/before.rules file for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

And add the following just before the `*filter` rules:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.99.99.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Now restart all of the services we've edited:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/pptpd restart
sudo sysctl -p
sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable
```

You'll need to forward the port 1723 on your router to your device. There's usually a preconfigured option for this on most modern routers.

I had a little trouble with Virgin's router, and it turned out I not only had to port forward, but also had to enable PPTP in the Firewall section of the settings.